# Python datetime issue - only year

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote a program where I get from sql value from Birthday of Klients and it is saved in `i=[]`, but I get a lot of Data where I get `datetime.datetime(xxxxx)` and I only need year because I would like to get the average of our clients.

The code:

```
import psycopg2

from datetime import *


#verbindung mit dem server bzw. db
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='test' host='192.168.1.10' password='test'")
    print ("Connectet **********")
except:
    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")
#verbindung mit der tabele
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("""SELECT bday from client""")
    print ("yes")
except:
    print ("I can't drop our test database!")

result = cur.fetchall()


i = []
for row in result:
    i.append(row)

print (i)
print (len(result))
```

Output:

```
...
(datetime.datetime(1967, 11, 7, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1976, 1, 1, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 3, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1969, 6, 6, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1977, 12, 26, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1944, 8, 22, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1954, 5, 31, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1942, 12, 4, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1967, 10, 16, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1941, 7, 1, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1937, 5, 17, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(2006, 6, 5, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1996, 11, 25, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1975, 3, 2, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 22, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1996, 7, 26, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1991, 4, 4, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(1938, 11, 29, 0, 0),), 
....
```

I need help resolving this issue.

Comment: Try converting this to only year using `strftime`

Comment: Use the ```year``` property of your ```datetime.datetime``` ojects. Something like this ```datetime.now().year```

Comment: In your code change ```i.append(row)``` to ```i.append(row.year)```.

Answer (score 0):

psycopg return tuples, if you get only 1 column from db it returns list of tuples with 1 element `[("a", ), ("a", )...]`

Because you get datetime, you can get only year from it like `row[0].year`

```
for row in result:
    i.append(row[0].year)
print(i)
```

or like this

```
i = [row[0].year for row in result]
print(i)
```

Comment: now if I change the i.append(row[0].year) or i.append(row.year) I get this:

Comment: i.append(row[0].year)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your code doing what you want:

```
import psycopg2
import datetime


# verbindung mit dem server bzw. db
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='test' host='192.168.1.10' password='test'")
    print("Connectet **********")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")
# verbindung mit der tabele
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("""SELECT bday from client""")
    print("yes")
except:
    print("I can't drop our test database!")

rows = cur.fetchall()

i = [row.year for row, *_ in rows]

print(i)
print(len(i))
```

Comment: i tryed this also but the "_ " is an error and without this it's the same problem like "i.append(row.year) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'"

Comment: Try the new version with Python 3.4 or higher

Comment: Hi accdias, thanks for helping me. My version of Python is 3.6.4

Comment: No, it was on version 3.6.4 with the error. What can it otherwise be ?

Comment: Try it again. That error was for the previous unedited version of my post.

Comment: Thank for not giving up :) .... I get a result but it is zero 0. 
Here the output:

Connectet **********
yes
[]
0

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It was the wrong list. Here the error :" File "as.py", line 38, in <module>
    i = [row.year for row, *_ in rows]
  File "as.py", line 38, in <listcomp>
    i = [row.year for row, *_ in rows]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'"